# Focus rectangles show sometimes on MFC dialogs in Windows 7

Tags: c++, mfc, controls

My OS version is Windows 7 Ultimate and VS version is 2013. I create a dialog based MFC project and just add a button on dialog. Focus rectangle (dotted rectangle) of the button shows sometimes right after dialog starting-up and sometimes not (even not after I click the button).

I really have no ideas about how this could happen. Is there someone knows the reason? Anyway, my goal is to remove focus rectangles on controls. Is there a simple way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot easily remove the focus rectangle. It is implemented by the dialog manager. You'd have to hook the [DrawFocusRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162479.aspx) API call. And for your first question: You installed some application that broke your system. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: Okay, I try to install a fresh OS in VM for testing. Thank you!

Comment: That broken software could be the virtualization application you are using. Or the display drivers.

Comment: Do you have Aero Enabled? Try to disable it. If the problem is caused by composition, you should read some documentation about DWM composition.

Comment: @sergiol After disable Aero, focus retangles show every-time. Searching DWM now...

Comment: @sergiol So, is there something wrong with my computer or OS? I also find this problem in Windows 10. How can I fix it? Thx

Comment: I don't know. If you wanna have a little fun, you can look to the image on my own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143211/enter-key-does-not-trigger-idok-default-push-button-action where you will see a dialog with focus rectangle on two buttons at the same time!